# Load in config file from different folder/classpath

Tags: java, rest, config

I am currently working on a REST API that need to load in a property from a config file that is in a different folder/classpath.

The path looks like this,

rest class: mainfolder/folder1/src/main/java/folder2/rest/rest.java

config file: mainfolder/folder3/props.conf

Right now, the code I have is this:

```
@GET
@Path("backups")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<FileInfo> getBackups(){
    String localStorage= "D:/Backup";
    Util util = new Util();
    try {
        Properties configFile = new java.util.Properties();
        final InputStream cfg = new FileInputStream("folder3/props.conf");
        try {
            configFile.load(cfg);
            localStorage = configFile.getProperty(FTPService.FTP_DOWNLOAD_TARGET);
            return util.listBackupFilesInLocalDir(localStorage);
        } finally {
            cfg.close();
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return util.listBackupFilesInLocalDir(localStorage);
}
```

Right now, I get an error 500 and it is because it can't find the `"folder/props.conf"` in the `FileInputStream`? It worked when I had the absolute file path on my system in there but since the system when its live ain't on my computer I need to be able to get the file wherver it is in the file system. Is this possible?

Comment: 'get the file werver it is in the filesystem'. Where *is* the file? Is it on the classpath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay it were very simple while i were testing i just put in the FileInputStream "../folder3/props.conf" and it found it!